# Replacing DOI links with open access DOI links

Tags: chrome, research, academia

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that replaces any link to `http://doi.org/[DOI]` present on a webpage with some open access DOI resolver, e.g. `oadoi.org` or `doai.io`.

For example, if the link is http://doi.org/10.1016/j.tree.2007.03.007 it should be replaced with either  http://oadoi.org/10.1016/j.tree.2007.03.007
 or  http://doai.io/10.1016/j.tree.2007.03.007 (or any other [open access DOI resolver](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/66593/452)).

---

I am aware of the Google Chrome extension [Find DOI in sci-hub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-doi-in-sci-hub/mponnjfbehdmaeiomjopicikfdckgbnk), which allows to conveniently grab the article from Sci-hub, but I would prefer to also easily access open access DOI resolvers, e.g. in case the article isn't available on Sci-hub, and avoid to unneccessarily use Sci-hub's bandwidth.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the [DOI Resolver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doi-resolver/goanbaknlbojfglcepjnankoobfakbpg) extension for Chrome. When both Autolink and Custom Resolver are enabled in Options, the feature that I believe you're looking for is exposed: "Rewrite existing dx.doi.org links to use the Custom DOI Resolver".